# Can we reduce pitch of a lead screw to reduce backlash of the lead screw?

Tags: gears

In gear design, the backlash is introduced in the design itself (not by tolerances of manufacturing) to allow free meshing of the gears. The backlash in the design can be minimized by reducing the pitch of the gears. For example, If the pitch of a gear halved the designed backlash can also be halved. Though the reduced pitch also reduces the torque capacity of the gear.
Similarly, is it possible to reduce the pitch of the lead screw to reduce the backlash in the design?

Comment: Yes and no - typically there would be a similar measured rotational backlash on the lead screw itself, but a reduced linear backlash on the position of the nut due to the reduced thread pitch.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Can you please elaborate?